# Android : Need help to set padding in styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, padding

This is my activity layout, i want to add a style for this activity in Manifest and the textview should not be visible in layout. I know i can do it programmatically as `setVisibility(View.GONE);` but it is a need and i have to do it with styles and style is to be given in manifest only. This is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/scroll_back">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--i am talking about this textview-->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Some Text"
                    android:padding="5dp"/>

                <!-- ends here.-->



                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Enter Name:"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="e.g John"
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to make sure I understand.  Do you want to make the textView not visible by editing the layout xml?

Comment: Not editing the layout but adding style in its activity tag in manifest & the scrollview should come up and hide the textview. You see there is `Some Text` on top and when style is added, `Enter Name` should take its place. Hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

This work for me put this in your res/value/style.xml

```
<style name="FontAwsomeFormFields">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/smallPadding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/smallPadding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/largPadding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/smallPadding</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/smallPadding</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/normalTextSize</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

than used in XML file

```
         <com.indussoft.lms.customUI.FontAwsomeTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHomeIcon"
                style="@style/FontAwsomeFormFields"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/fa_long_arrow_left"
                android:textSize="@dimen/largeTextSize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your style.xml:

```
 <style name="MyTextviewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"> 
     <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>      
</style>
```

Now in your textView do this:

```
                <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Some Text"
                style="@style/MyTextviewStyle"
                android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Comment: I know that, thnx but i want to add padding to whole activity so that the textview comes out of layout and becomes invisible.

Comment: I can not understand what you are saying ?

Comment: Suppose an activity has vertical 10 lines each named according to their position. I want the 4th line to come to top and 1st, 2nd & 3rd should not be visible now as the 4th overrided the three. Can i do it here with styles.

Comment: Then use list view man. put the item as per your order and do not add those which you don't want to display.

Comment: Oh!! i have a .smali file of a layout and i just wanted to hide the textview on top. I can't find the text in that file and i can't modify the .smali file, that's what it was about. :(